# Pointer to Function Code from K&R

Tags: c, pointers

Pg 119 of K&R shows qsort written with pointers to functions:

```
if ((nlines = readlines(lineptr, MAXLINES)) >= 0)
    qsort((void **) lineptr, 0, nlines -1,
        (int (*)(void *, void *))(numeric ? numcmp : strcmp));
```

In this code lineptr is cast as a pointer to pointer to void.  It is a pointer to an array of char pointers.  However the code can also be written as:

```
    qsort((void *) lineptr, 0, nlines-1,
```

and it still runs perfectly.  Does the compiler just figure it out?  Why write the code one way or the other?

Comment: `qsort()` expects the first parameter to be `(void *)`. I am assuming the compiler is casting the `(void **)` back to `(void *)` implicitly.

Comment: Are you also using the declaration of `qsort` from that page?

Comment: Yes, I am using the declaration from pg 119

Comment: A function with a `void *` parameter accepts any kind of pointer. That's quite dangerous, since the caller might pass any kind of crappy data to such a function (in your case a pointer to `void *`, which is nothing like the data you want to sort). Still it has its uses for desigining more or less generic code, for lack of C++-like mechanisms.

Answer (score 1):

In that declaration, the first argument is of type `void* lineptr[]`, which is equivalent to `void** lineptr`.

If you call using

```
qsort((void *) lineptr, 0, nlines-1);
```

it still works because you can convert a `void*` to any other pointer type in C. It is better to use the exactly matching type but that's more of a coding guideline than a requirement by the language.

It's possible, since I am not certain, that when the book was written, implicit conversion from `void*` to `void**` was not supported by the compilers. Hence, the book uses `(void**)lineptr` as the first argument.

Comment: That makes sense.  Thanks!